# Eclipse pom.xml content assistant

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I'm new to Eclipse. I'm using Eclipse Kepler to create Maven project, everything works fine except when i'm working with pom.xml the content assistant doesn't give me auto complete just like Netbeans does. Below is the screenshot from Netbeans
[image]

My question is can Eclipse be like that in term of gives me auto complete on pom.xml?
Do i need plugin for it?
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically 2 ways for doing that:

1. Refer to the XML's DTD/XSD in its header, so the simple Eclipse XML editor can help you in a minimal way (e.g., check well-formedness, offers *Ctrl+Space* assist, etc.).
2. A better option is to install *m2e* which is the official Eclipse Maven integration plug-in. It should be available through the *Install new software...* menu item by default, just search for it. It has quite a heavy support for Maven projects (specific editors, repo browsers, it does update the project configuration automatically, helps you select the dependencies, hanldes multi-module projects, makes easier to import Maven-based projects, etc.)

Comment: ahh my bad, newest eclipse has built in support for maven, no need to install m2e plugin, it's already installed. All i did was rebuild maven index repository within Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

How to Setup Maven AutoComplete:

1) Download and install the maven plugin into Eclipse. I think the link is this http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/

2) In Eclipse, go to Windows tab -> Preferences

[image]
3) Got Maven folder from the left-hand menu. Make sure the three boxes I circled are checked. Click Ok
[image]

One of the boxes lets you do AutoComplete. I forget which one.

4) Right-click on your project and go to Maven -> Update Project.

[image]

5) You're now done! You should be able to do autocomplete by pressing Control+Spacebar:

[image]